# df showing different disk sizes in 14.04 and 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, 14.04, hard-drive

I have several servers on Rackspace and have been moving some of them over from 12.04 to 14.04.  One of the features they have is called Block Storage which lets you attach an external disk.  These can be reattached to any server and are not dependent on which OS you are using.  In Ubuntu 12.04 I had created a 150GB partition and df shows that it is 150GB.  But I created the same in 14.04, copied the files over, but df says it is only 141GB.  Upon noticing this I realized that my other disks are similarly smaller than they should be (e.g. a 100GB partition is only 94GB).

I'm completely aware that 5% or so of disk space is reserved automatically by the OS.  This isn't that even though it seems every Google result regarding df and missing space seems to be this.  I played with this number just to confirm and only the available percentage changed.

Has df changed in the past two years or am I missing something?

Output in 12.04

(df)

> /dev/xvdb1               150G   95G   48G  67% /external

(fdisk)

Disk /dev/xvdb: 161.1 GB, 161061273600 bytes

> 65 heads, 3 sectors/track, 1613193 cylinders, total 314572800 sectors
>
> Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk identifier: 0x26e02677
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>
> /dev/xvdb1            2048   314572799   157285376   83  Linux

Output in 14.04

(df)

> /dev/xvdc1          141G   93G   41G  70% /external2

(fdisk)

> Disk /dev/xvdc: 161.1 GB, 161061273600 bytes
>
> 65 heads, 3 sectors/track, 1613193 cylinders, total 314572800 sectors
>
> Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk identifier: 0x4a1274d9
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>
> /dev/xvdc1            2048   314572799   157285376   83  Linux